# Firebase dynamic links to reset password : not configured for the current project

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-functions, firebase-dynamic-links

I am using a Cloud Function to generate a password-reset-link through the admin sdk.

I need to handle the action link in my website and not my mobile app.

my action code settings looks like :

```
ActionCodeSettings codeSettings = ActionCodeSettings(
        url: "https://example.com/links/reset",
      handleCodeInApp: false,
      dynamicLinkDomain: "https://example.com/links"
    );
```

and i have also tried :

```
ActionCodeSettings codeSettings = ActionCodeSettings(
        url: "https://example.com/links/reset",
      handleCodeInApp: false,
    );
```

Both gives me the following error :

```
FirebaseAuthError: The provided dynamic link domain is not configured or authorized for the current project.
```

I am simply using the : `admin.auth().generatePasswordResetLink(data.email, actionCodeSettings)` method in an `onCall` https request to my function.

I have of course setup dynamic links for my project and my project is hosted fine with `Firebase Hosting`.

I have also added this to my `firebase.json` file :

```
"rewrites": [ {
  "source": "/links/**", 
  "dynamicLinks": true
} ]
```

As stated in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/custom-domains).

What i am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i generate the `ActionCodeSettings` from flutter it doesn't work.

However, if in my NodeJS code I implement :

```
const actionCodeSettings = {
    url: "https://example.com/links",
    handleCodeInApp: false
  };
```

It's working.

In the logs i could see that the param `dynamicLinkDomain` was set to null and passed even if i was not using it.